# How can I tell if an Intent has been launched by parse

Tags: android, android-intent, parse-platform

If I overwrite  ParsePushBroadcastReceiver i see that intent extras are passed to the intent,

- Which of this extras (if they do) refer to the fact that this intent has been created by parse?
- How can i pass/access this flag "launched by parse" through all the activities that will be opened starting from this intent?
- Do this extras are passed in the non overwritten version of ParsePushBroadcastReceiver?

  ```
  public class Receiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver {
      @Override
      public void onPushOpen(Context context, Intent intent) {
          Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
          i.putExtras(intent.getExtras());
          i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
          context.startActivity(i);
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Already sending `intent.getExtras()` to Activity then what is issue?

Comment: I wander which are those extras and which of them refer to Parse, how can I access them and tell if they are originated from Parse and to know if they are propagated across all activities after launching the intent. Also I'd like to know if this extras are already sent by using the default ParsePushBroadcastReceiver.